# Creating JavaScript Project Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to create a JavaScript project Ionic 4, but there is no command to do that, so what I can do to make new Ionic 4 JavaScript project?
Thanks

Comment: So do you want to make an ionic project without angular or what are you asking?

Comment: yes I want to make ionic project  with vanilla JavaScript

Comment: @Riyad Khalifeh You could import the vanilla Javascript into the Angular based project like Ionic but it's a bad practice, but sometimes it will save you much time, do it when necessary only.

Answer (score 1):

you can inject the dependencies directly in your index.html  , as you can see in [the official doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/cdn#using-ionic-from-a-cdn):

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/css/ionic.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">
```